# Does tabview in Android use Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I had a general question on Android. For example if I am using tabs in Android -> is that handled with Fragments. Similarly if I was to use a Navigation Drawer is that a fragement as well ? I think i quite did not get the concept of Fragments there.

For example I was to build the following screen:

[image]

What would the xml template include everything. From my guess it would have a tab view and then a list view and a fab button. So in this case would I use a fragment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build this kind of layout, you must use `CoordinatorLayout` as parent layout and you should use `AppBarLayout` with `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Then use `TabLayout` where you have to show these tabs in bottom of screen use `ViewPager`

Or you can use simple `FrameLayout` where you can add fragments on tap of each tab.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="260dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorAccent"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <!-- Your Header layout goes Here -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minHeight="160dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                    <!-- Content inside your header layout just like image ot other info -->

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <!-- Your Tablayout goes here-->
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#5be5ad"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
        <!-- Your Viewpager goes here-->
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

     <!-- your FAB goes here-->
      <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
          android:id="@+id/fab"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
          app:elevation="6dp"
          app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
          app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
          android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hope it will help you.